# IOS -- how do I move a UILabel in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create a (not very) custom UITableView with a button on the left side of the cell, and text to the right of the button.

I try to calculate where to put the UILabel that is part of the cell but changing the frame has no effect (and it doesn't even appear to be computed -- all zeros).

My question is: when is the frame size for the label computed?  (So that changes will have an effect).

Is this the right way to do it?

Code snippets below.
First is from the cell init (called in response to the dequeueReusable...
and yes, 'buttonColor', 'onTapSel', 'buttonFrame', and 'buttonColor' are "member variables (File static globals)

```
- (id)initWithStyle: (UITableViewCellStyle)style
    reuseIdentifier: (NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (nil == buttonColor)
    {   buttonColor = kDefaultCellButtonColor; }

    if (nil == onTapSel)
    {   onTapSel = @selector(defaultCellButtonTapped:); }

    if (self)
    {
        EGCellButton * cellButton = (EGCellButton *)[[EGCellButton alloc ] initWithFrame:buttonFrame ];
        cellButton.backgroundColor = buttonColor;
        [cellButton  setTitle:buttonLabel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cellButton addTarget:self action:(onTapSel) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self setCellButton:cellButton];

        float xx = buttonFrame.origin.x + buttonFrame.size.width + 5;
        CGRect frame = self.textLabel.frame;
        frame.origin.x   += xx;
        self.textLabel.frame = frame;
        [self addSubview:cellButton];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and now from the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EGButtonTableCellID";
    EGButtonTableCell * cell = (EGButtonTableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.cellButton.indexPath = indexPath;

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel.text = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    float xx = cell.cellButton.frame.origin.x + cell.cellButton.frame.size.width + 5;
    CGRect frame = cell.textLabel.frame;
    frame.origin.x   += xx;
    cell.textLabel.frame = frame;

    return cell;
}
```

The result being that the button appears on the left side of the cell (as intended), but the first letter I see in the label is 'g', so the first 6 chars are hidden behind the button (not intended).

When I dump the values in the frame, all except origin.x are zero in both methods.

This should work, yes?  no?  why not?  etc.
Thank you all very much!

:bp:

Comment: Where are you setting the value of buttonFrame?

Comment: Trying to make custom cells in `cellForRow…` is a huge pain.  I know it seems easier at first, but you should always just subclass UITableViewCell and do it that way.  (Follow Maggie's answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set frame for your UILabel and UIButton in `layoutSubviews` method of your custom UITableViewCell

See Apple Documentation on the subject:

> Subclasses can override this method as needed to perform more precise
>   layout of their subviews. You should override this method only if the
>   autoresizing and constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not
>   offer the behavior you want. You can use your implementation to set
>   the frame rectangles of your subviews directly.

Comment: **Important**: Be sure you call `[super layoutSubviews]` as the 1st line of your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom UITableViewCell, access objects in the class or implement methods.

CustomCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *customCellLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *customCellButton;

@end
```

CustomCell.m

```
#import "TLCell.h"
@implementation CustomCell

@synthesize customCellLabel, customCellButton
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        customCellLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        customCellLabel.frame = CGRectMake(180, 0, 60, 30);
        [self addSubview:customCellLabel];

        customCellButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        customCellButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30);
        [self addSubview:customCellButton];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

CustomTableView.m

```
/* --- */
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    [cell.customLabel setText:@"hello"];
    // [cell.
    [cell.customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
/* --- */
```